# Como exibir somente metade do background-color da div

Tags: html, css

Preciso que mostra somente 50% do bg da DIV, tem como?

```
#coberturas legend{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding:10px 20px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:rgba(55,57,62,0.8);
    width:320px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition:all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s;

}
```

esta div está sobreposta a outra;

Comment: Poderias postar também juntamente com a tua pergunta o código com que estás a tentar fazer isto? E se possível adicionar mais detalhes, porque a pergunta parece estar um pouco vaga...

Comment: O que exatamente você quer fazer? O quem tem dentro dessa div? Definir uma altura com `overflow:hidden;` no css não resolve? Precisamos de mais detalhes pra poder te ajudar

Comment: vou editar o post, com o codigo

Comment: era [**disto**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71222/11886) que estavas à procura @GustavoCardoso ?

Comment: Votei por reabrir, edição 6 parece que já deixou claro o objetivo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei se queres que seja 50% da `div` em termos de ser na horizontal, ou se em termos de 50% sendo na vertical. então vou postar aqui duas possíveis maneiras de se fazer isso de ambas as formas.

Este será o suposto HTML para gerar as 2 `divs`. O `id` container é incluído apenas para manter as duas `divs filho` dentro da `div pai - container` usando a propriedade `position:relative;` que irás ver no código CSS abaixo após o exemplo do código HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="coberturas1"></div>
    <div id="coberturas2"></div>
</div>
```

**Se estiveres à procura de fazer isso horizontalmente, o CSS será: http://jsfiddle.net/v7ecw3ah/**

```
#container{position:relative;}
#coberturas1 {
    background-color: rgba(55,57,62,0.8);
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
}
#coberturas2 {
    background-color: #efc94d;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;

    /* código para mostrar apenas 50% da div Cinzenta (coberturas1) */
    position:absolute;
    top:5px; /* muda este valor para "0" - Isto foi apenas mostrar o que está a acontecer por detrás da div */
    right:25%; /* 25% significa metade (que neste caso será 50%) do tamanho de ambas as divs */
}
```

---

**Se estiveres à procura de fazer isso verticalmente, o CSS será: http://jsfiddle.net/v7ecw3ah/1/**

```
#container{position:relative;}
#coberturas1 {
    background-color: rgba(55,57,62,0.8);
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
}
#coberturas2 {
    background-color: #efc94d;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;

    /* código para mostrar apenas 50% da div Cinzenta (coberturas1) */
    position:absolute;
    top:150px; /* 150px significa metade (que neste caso será 50%) do tamanho de ambas as divs */
    left:5px; /* muda este valor para "0" - Isto foi apenas mostrar o que está a acontecer por detrás da div */
}
```

Comment: Isso não vai me ajudar, preciso que a div ainda esteja la, mas só mostre a metade, ou seja a div vai ocupar todo o espaço, porem o background precisa ficar na metade, tinha errado, peço desculpa

Answer (score 0):

Sendo uma "cor" você pode usar [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

```css
.horizontal .inner, .vertical .inner, .diagonal .inner {
    width:320px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.horizontal .inner {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00f 0%, #00f 50%, #f00 51%, #f00 100%);
}

.vertical .inner {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #00f 0%, #00f 50%, #f00 51%, #f00 100%);
}

.diagonal .inner {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #00f 0%, #00f 50%, #f00 51%, #f00 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal">
    <div class="inner">
        Olá mundo
    </div>
</div>

<div class="vertical">
    <div class="inner">
        Olá mundo
    </div>
</div>

<div class="diagonal">
    <div class="inner">
        Olá mundo
    </div>
</div>
```

Acaso queira compatibilidade com navegadores mais antigos, use estas propriedades:

```
/*Fallback para navegadores sem suporte*/
background: #00f;

 /* FF3.6+ */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #00f 0%, #00f 50%, #f00 51%, #f00 100%);

/* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #00f), color-stop(50%, #f00), color-stop(51%,#f00), color-stop(100%,#f00));

/* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #00f 0%, #00f 50%, #f00 51%, #f00 100%);

/* Opera 11.10+ (não webkit/blink) */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #00f 0%,#00f 50%,#f00 51%, #f00 100%);

/* IE10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #00f 0%,#00f 50%,#f00 51%, #f00 100%);

/* CSS3*/
background: linear-gradient(to right, #00f 0%,#00f 50%,#f00 51%, #f00 100%);

/* Fallback para IE6 ao IE9 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00f', endColorstr='#f00',GradientType=1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar essa ferramenta online, mais muito útil pra emular sua `div`:

http://makewebsimple.net/cssdivbuilder

Pra gerar o gradiente utilizo essa outra ferramenta online:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Exp

```css
.teste{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  border: 1px rgb(89,89,89) solid;

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%, rgba(35,111,183,1) 24%, rgba(41,137,216,0.66) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,0.65) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,0)), color-stop(24%,rgba(35,111,183,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(41,137,216,0.66)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(35,111,183,1) 24%,rgba(41,137,216,0.66) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,0.65) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(35,111,183,1) 24%,rgba(41,137,216,0.66) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,0.65) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(35,111,183,1) 24%,rgba(41,137,216,0.66) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,0.65) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(35,111,183,1) 24%,rgba(41,137,216,0.66) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,0.65) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001e5799', endColorstr='#007db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div id="teste" class="teste"></div>
```

No seu caso ficaria algo assim:

```css
.teste {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;

  border: 1px rgb(89,89,89) solid;
  
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(239,242,48,1) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(34,125,203,0) 52%, rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(239,242,48,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(41,137,216,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,1)), color-stop(52%,rgba(34,125,203,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(239,242,48,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(34,125,203,0) 52%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(239,242,48,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(34,125,203,0) 52%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(239,242,48,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(34,125,203,0) 52%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(239,242,48,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(34,125,203,0) 52%,rgba(125,185,232,0) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eff230', endColorstr='#007db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
  #coberturas{
    font:Lucida Sans;   
    display:block;
    bottom:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#FF9911;

    width:200px;



  }
```

```html
<div id="teste" class="teste">
  <h2> Coberturas </h2>
  <div id="coberturas" class="coberturas"></div>
  <ul>
    <a href="fotos.php?id=5">   <li><img src="imagens/01.jpg"  width="100" height="100" /> <br/>
      <legend> <span>29/05/2015 - TUPACIGUARA MG</span> <br /> <h1>EXPO CAPITU</h1></legend></li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```