# Como Exibir Metade De Background

Tags: html, css

Tenho duas `<div>`, uma está sobreposta a outra.
E preciso que a que está em cima, só mostre metade do *background*. Ou seja, a outra metade vai ficar transparente pra que a outra metade da `<div>` de baixo fique visível.

Obs: a `<div>` tem que estar em cima da outra por completo, só preciso que o *background* fique pela metade.

```
 <div id="coberturas">
    <h2> Coberturas </h2>
   <div class="sp"></div>
    <ul>
     <a href="fotos.php?id=<?php echo $row_RS_coberturas['id']; ?>">   <li><img src="imagens/01.jpg"  width="320" height="320" /> <br/>
        <legend> <span>29/05/2015 - TUPACIGUARA MG</span> <br /> <h1>EXPO CAPITU</h1></legend></li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#coberturas legend{
font:Lucida Sans;   
padding:10px 20px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#FF9911;

    width:320px;



}
#coberturas legend a{
text-decoration:none;
font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
background-color:rgba(0,210,210,0);
color:rgba(0,210,210,1);
color:#FFFFFF;
}
#coberturas legend h1{
position:relative;
font:Trebuchet; 
margin-top:3px;
font-size:22px;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
#coberturas legend:hover{opacity: 1;
background-color:#FF6600;


}
#coberturas ul{
margin-left:-30px;
margin-top:20px;
}
#coberturas img{
border: 0;
    display:block;
    transition:all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s;
}
#coberturas img:hover{
opacity:0.8;
-ms-transform: scale(0.98); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(0.98); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: scale(0.98);


}
#coberturas a:hover{
background-color:#FF6600;
opacity:0.8;
-ms-transform: scale(1.03); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: scale(1.03)

}
```

Comment: poste seu codigo e aonde está tendo dificuldade, para podermos lhe ajudar

Comment: Essa pergunta e uma duplicada de: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71208/como-exibir-somente-metade-do-background-color-da-div

Comment: Não duplique as perguntas, por favor tente a minha resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71389/3635 eu já votei por reabrir a outra pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a técnica de *gradient*, onde em seu [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) você utilize o [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) (que pode não funcionar em alguns browsers antigos), para fazer com que seu background seja metade transparente e metade visível (50%), sendo que a `div` ainda pode cobrir completamente a outra.

Veja um exemplo simples de como pode ser feito:

> Onde a `div` de fundo é vermelha e a metade da `div` superior é preta.

```css
div.fundo {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
div.metade {
  height: 100px;
  /* background com metade transparente horizontal */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 50%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="fundo">
  <div class="metade">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Exemplo também no jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/zej8sqzx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é válido no seu problema, mas usei transform pra resolver isso.

Ambas as divs tem as mesmas dimensões, mas a segunda com o transform é reduzida a 50% de seu tamanho.

Caso o conteúdo fique estranho eu recomendo usar esse background em um ::before.

```
::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    [atributos de background do .content]
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/500/300/sports");
}
.container .content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
      -ms-transform-origin: top;
          transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5);
      -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5);
          transform: scaleY(0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```